VALIDATE CONSTRAINT of Foreign key pointing to partitioned table for individual partitions instead of everything at once
I have a partitioned table user(id, tenant_id) partitioned on tenant_id that has a hundred partitions (user_1000, user_2000 etc.)
I have a separate existing table events(id, user_id, tenant_id) that I want to now add a foreign key to user to. That's easy enough with a NOT VALID:
ALTER TABLE events
    ADD CONSTRAINT events_fk_users FOREIGN KEY (user_id, tenant_id) REFERENCES users(id, organization_id) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT VALID;

Now the real issue comes at validating the foreign key. I know this is optional, but for the sake of keeping clean DDL, I'd preferably try to keep every constraint validated.
The events table has a significant amount of entries, and there are a lot of users
When running ALTER TABLE VALIDATE CONSTRAINT events_fk_users, it takes ages to run. This is because it's actually running the worst possible query it can, iterating over all partitions at once - (you can see this query if you cancel the validation):
SELECT fk."user_id", fk."tenant_id"
FROM ONLY "public"."events" fk
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "public"."users" pk ON (pk."id" OPERATOR (pg_catalog.=) fk."user_id" AND
                                                              pk."tenant_id" OPERATOR (pg_catalog.=)
                                                              fk."tenant_id")
WHERE pk."id" IS NULL
  AND (fk."user_id" IS NOT NULL AND fk."tenant_id" IS NOT NULL);

I thought about validating the "sub"constraints that get created automatically when adding a partitioned FOREIGN KEY.
(You can see them by running this query:)
SELECT conname, pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(r.oid, true) as condef
FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint r
WHERE r.conrelid in ('events'::regclass)

events_user_id_tenant_id_fkey - FOREIGN KEY (user_id, tenant_id) REFERENCES users_1000(id, user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT VALID
events_user_id_tenant_id_fkey1 - ...
events_user_id_tenant_id_fkey2 - ...
events_user_id_tenant_id_fkey3 - ...
...

However, validating those in isolation like VALIDATE CONSTRAINT events_user_id_tenant_id_fkey doesn't work. It's valid, but it tries to validate every single entry in the table against that constraint, which breaks once the first partition key is outside the partitioned table's range.
As this is a cloud hosted instance, I do not have access to modify the definition table and just set the validated flag to true.
I'm running dry on ideas, and might just have to have a lengthy VALIDATE CONSTRAINT query running.
Is there an established way to deal with this? I couldn't find any resources anywhere about this problem.
We're using PSQL 15.8

Why is the long running ALTER TABLE ... VALIDATE CONSTRAINT a problem?

While you don't have superuser access to the system catalog pg_constraint any dirty tricks are out of reach.

@LaurenzAlbe We prefer being able to run, as long as possible, any migration code as part of automated migrations that are short-lived. The tables will only grow and what takes 30 minutes today, will take 1-2-3-4 hours tomorrow.

@ErwinBrandstetter that's what I was thinking of, setting the convalidated flag.
